# What is the best way to import technical analysis of stock prices?

Tags: r, stock, technical-indicator

Here is my data frame:

[image]

Each row has different dates. If I want to import RSI for the stock prices, what is the best way to do this?

The raw data of the data frame is:

```
mdate   edate   tickers adjusted1   adjusted2   adjusted3   close1  close2  close3  high1   high2   high3   low1    low2    low3    open1   open2   open3   volume1 volume2 volume3
2015-10-30  2015-11-04  TK  29.12   29.08   29.59   32.13   32.09   32.65   32.38   32.43   32.95   31.1    31.52   32.1    31.62   31.81   32.18   487000  715900  846100
2015-11-02  2015-11-05  TGP 20.42   20.57   21.08   24.84   25.02   25.64   25.09   25.31   25.81   24.14   24.4    24.9    25.09   24.8    25.05   208500  120800  270900
2015-11-03  2015-11-06  DNR 3.54    3.7 3.91    3.54    3.7 3.91    3.6 3.8 4.07    3.25    3.46    3.76    3.42    3.5 3.8 10959500    10429800    13534400
```

Comment: For a quick start, I highlighted your sample data, copied it, and did `do.call(rbind, strsplit(readLines("clipboard"), "\\s+"))`, and it gave me a character `matrix`; conversion to a `data.frame` and type-converting each column is straight-forward.

Comment: you can check up `TTR` package, it has implementation of plenty tech indicators, including RSI, BolBands, Mov. averages, MACD etc...

Comment: @JacobJacox Do you know how to import shares outstanding? Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too long for comment, so here is an example of possible import/analysis

```
library(quantmod)
library(magrittr)
library(TTR)

names = c("AAPL","AMZN","ANF") ## amazon, aaple, abb & Fitc -- tickers
my_portfolio = names

stocks <- lapply(my_portfolio,function(x){
  tryCatch(
    {
      w = getSymbols(x,auto.assign = F,warnings = F)
      message(x," Collected!")
      Sys.sleep(0.05)
      return(w)
    },
    error= function(cond)return(data.frame())
  )

})
names(stocks) <- my_portfolio


### analysis


stock = stocks$AAPL

# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03  12.32714  12.36857 11.70000   11.97143   309579900      10.36364
# 2007-01-04  12.00714  12.27857 11.97429   12.23714   211815100      10.59366
# 2007-01-05  12.25286  12.31428 12.05714   12.15000   208685400      10.51822
# 2007-01-08  12.28000  12.36143 12.18286   12.21000   199276700      10.57016
# 2007-01-09  12.35000  13.28286 12.16429   13.22429   837324600      11.44823
# 2007-01-10  13.53571  13.97143 13.35000   13.85714   738220000      11.99609



rsi_ind = RSI(price = stock$AAPL.Close)
macd_ind = MACD(x = stock$AAPL.Close)

## so on
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I also import shares outstanding of stocks?

Comment: I am not sure i understand?  Via quantmod u can access stock that are on yahoo finance, but you have to provide a ticker.